# Handling an array of objects rather than an object with nested objects in angular 2 form

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I am using angular 2 form to populate and edit information in my app. When it comes to images for the data schema on the backend, it has looked like this:

```
media {
       featured: "Url string", <!-- designated default image -->
       other: {
               img1: "Url string", <!-- secondary images -->
               img2: "Url string",
               img3: "Url string",
               img4: "Url string",
               img5: "Url string",
               img6: "Url string"
              }
      }
```

However now it has been changed to look like this:

```
media: [
    {
       thumbs: {
                 default: "Url string",
               }
       primary: boolean, <!-- whether or not image is the default image -->
       type: string,
       raw: "Url string of image"
    {
```

]

My current form.ts handles the image like this:

```
 let featured = '';
 let img1 = '';
 let img2 = '';
 let img3 = '';
 let img4 = '';
 let img5 = '';
 let img6 = '';


  if (this.otherMode) {
  const pendingCards = this.pendingCardsComponent.getPendingCard(this.id);
  featured = pendingCards.media.featured;
  img1 = pendingCards.media.other.img1;
  img2 = pendingCards.media.other.img2;
  img3 = pendingCards.media.other.img3;
  img4 = pendingCards.media.other.img4;
  img5 = pendingCards.media.other.img5;
  img6 = pendingCards.media.other.img6;

  this.cardForm = new FormGroup({
  'title': new FormControl(cardTitle),
  'media': new FormGroup({
    'featured': new FormControl(featured, Validators.maxLength(300)),
    'other': new FormGroup({
      'img1': new FormControl(img1, Validators.maxLength(300)),
      'img2': new FormControl(img2, Validators.maxLength(300)),
      'img3': new FormControl(img3, Validators.maxLength(300)),
      'img4': new FormControl(img4, Validators.maxLength(300)),
      'img5': new FormControl(img5, Validators.maxLength(300)),
      'img6': new FormControl(img6, Validators.maxLength(300)),
    }),
  }),

    private storeCardUrl = 'httpURL';

 onSubmit(value: string){
  let formData:Card = this.cardForm.value;
  // let formData: Card[] = this.cardForm.value;
  let body = JSON.stringify(formData);
  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  return this.http.post(this.storeCardUrl, body, {headers: headers})
    .map((response: Response) =>  response.json())
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
    // console.log(formData);
 }
```

And the form.html section that handles the image rendering and edit looks like this:

```
 <div formGroupName="media">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <md-input-container class="mdcontainer">
        <input
          mdInput placeholder="Card Primary Image"
          type="text"
          id="featured"
          formControlName="featured"
          class="form-control"
          #featured>
      </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img [src]="featured.value" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Secondary Images  -->
<div formGroupName="other">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <md-input-container class="mdcontainer">
        <input
          mdInput placeholder="Secondary Image 1"
          type="text"
          id="img1"
          formControlName="img1"
          class="form-control"
          #img1>
      </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img [src]="img1.value" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I don't understand is handling Media as an array that can still be pulled into my form.html and be able to display the image that I want it to. The old model allowed calling img1/img2/etc. but new model as an array doesn't have any objects outside of the object that contains the Url and other fields. I know that I can create a formArray, with a formGroup and some formControls to get the correct structure but being able to get those images correctly on the html is giving me trouble.

Any help/suggestions/tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, you know how to make the form, but you don't ? I'm sorry I don't quite get you : what is your question here ? How to build the form, or how to display the images ?

Comment: Apologies on my crappy question. I think I understand how to build the form with the array model but I don't know how to display the image with my current html structure.

Comment: No problem really, I'm just trying to wrap my head around it to help you. If I don't make any errors, you provide an input to your users to change the url of the pictures, and you use it a a `src` attribute in your image tags, right ?

Comment: Yes. Allowing them to "preview" the image url they just pasted into the input.

Comment: Ok I see now. If your replace your image tag with a p tag and {{featured.value}} , does it display the input value ?

Comment: @trichetriche unfortunately I don't know. The schema change has already been made and I can't get access to images through the old model/means. Apologies

Comment: That's the point, I'm asking you to do it now with the new version :) unless what you're saying is that the model changed, but the html didn't ? Ooooh is that your question, you want to change the html based on your new model?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes. If it is possible with the current html structure or not. If not what would the html structure have to look like when trying to display/edit an image with the new model?

Comment: That certainly won't be the same if the model has changed. To manage that, you just have to look at your model and make the ngModel tags match with it. It won't make a big difference but it will change a bit

Comment: The tags were pulling from nested objects but now with media being an array. I am not understanding to bind those. How can I make sure I am binding to image were primary is true, etc.?  **also thanks for investing the time**